# BigQuery, using ARRAY_AGG to create comma delimited results

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I need to make

[image: this table]

generate results like this below, to create a CSV. The query needs to show all values **Familia** and **Year** belonging to the same SKU together being comma separated

```
SKU;FAMILIA;ANO
203939393;FAMILIA COROLLA, FAMILIA CBU, FAMILIA HILUX;2008,2009,2010
```

I'm using BIGQUERY and try this function

```
SELECT  FORMAT("%T", ARRAY_AGG(x limit 100)) AS array_agg
FROM `Toyoparts.csv_compatibilidade` AS x
```

But it just makes a huge array. If anyone could help?

Comment: I don't think SQL Server and BigQuery are the same thing. Certainly SQL Server doesn't appear to have a ARRAY_AGG function. And we prefer formatted text for data over images.

Comment: I removed inconsistent tags , please tag only database you are using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [string_agg](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/aggregate_functions#string_agg) instead:

```
SELECT
  sku,
  string_agg(familia limit 100) as familia,
  string_agg(anomodelo limit 100) as anomodelo
FROM `Toyoparts.csv_compatibilidade`
group by sku
```